# Pyramid inside a rectangle pattern

Tags: java

I am having difficulty finding a suitable solution to stop the recurrence of blanks after the stars have finished printing, and this caused me a problem in printing Yemeni lines diverging, so I want them to be straight and similar to this pattern

[image]

```
public class task {

    public static void pettren1(int high, int width) {
        high = 11;
        width = 14;

        //Overline

        for (int i = 0; i <= width /2; i++) {
            System.out.print(" _");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = high; i > 0; i--) {
      //The left line and the space
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int j = high-1; j >= i; j--)
                System.out.print(" ");
            //for the stars
            for (int k = 1; k <= (i * 2 - 7); k++)
                System.out.print("*");

            //The right line and the space
            for (int j = high-1; j >= i; j--)
                System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print("|");


            System.out.println();
        }
        //The bottom line
        for (int i = 0; i <= width /2; i++) {
            System.out.print(" _");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pettren1(0, 0);


    }

}
```

my output

[image]

Comment: yeah, that is right  am asking how can solve this problem, because I could not fix it,

Comment: Looks like you are close, I'd recommend either debugging through the code to see what happens after the last row with stars, or if you prefer, just output useful details eg before the loops indexed on j, output the value of high-1 and i, to see which value is a bit bigger than you want. If you can write the solution up to where you have got to, you will be able to figure out where the problem is, and once you know that, fixing it will be easy. Good luck, and if you can't get any further post an update, but I'm sure you can crack this.

Comment: Are you asking this as a new question? Shouldn't you have just fixed the original question and then gotten it reopened? You had some good comments and answers.

Comment: Or this might be a good one to go through your algorithm with pencil and paper to see what is going on

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. Please take Chris' advice.

Comment: I am not asking for a homework-writing service as you think, am a beginner in programming and I jut start it soon. am trying to figure out where am I wrong.

Comment: *Hint:* Right now you have 3 main loops (overline, content, and bottom line). The problem is that the content has two parts, the part with the triangle and the part with the blank lines. Trying to handle both in a single main loop is complicating matters, so you should split the middle main loop in two.

Answer (score 0):

You should have implemented a counter of printed characters and in the third nested loop printing spaces on the right side use this value to print spaces until `width` is reached:

```java
for (int i = high; i > 0; i--) {
//The left line and the space
    System.out.print("|");
    int c = 0;
    for (int j = high-1; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        c++;
    }
    //for the stars
    for (int k = 1; k <= (i * 2 - 7); k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
        c++;
    }

    //The spaces and the right line
    for (int j = c; j <= width; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("|");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Also, it is not quite clear why "reverse" loops have been used.
Incrementing loops can do the same:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < high; i++) {
    int c = 0;
//The left line and the space
    System.out.print("|");
    
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        c++;
    }
    //for the stars
    for (int k = 0; k < width - 2 * i + 1; k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
        c++;
    }

    //The right line and the space
    for (int j = c; j <= width; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    
    System.out.print("|");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Both codes print the same pyramid:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|***************|
| ************* |
|  ***********  |
|   *********   |
|    *******    |
|     *****     |
|      ***      |
|       *       |
|               |
|               |
|               |
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

---

`String::repeat`-based solution calculating the number of stars beforehand:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < high; i++) {
    int stars = Math.max(0, width - 2 * i + 1);
    System.out.printf("|%s%s%s|%n", " ".repeat(i), "*".repeat(stars), " ".repeat(width + 1 - i - stars));
}
```